# Android 2.1 WebView and keyboard input

Tags: html, android, webview

When Android 2.1 focuses on a text field in a WebView while in Landscape, it does this below.  It takes the entire field input area and fills the tiny strip of available screen.

The problem here is that when you hit that "Next" button, you have enough idea what field you are in.

Is there a way to improve this with some sort of prompt so the user at least knows the type of data they are expected to enter in that field?  I tried using a

```
<label for="my_field_id">My Caption</label>
<input type="text" id="my_field_id"/>
```

hoping that it would pull text from there, but it seemed to have no effect.

---

Also, I just tried adding a `placeholder="Foo Bar"` to the input field.  This sort of worked.  The prompt appeared in the field, and when tapped it appeared in the fullscreen input area.  But the problem was that the placeholder was kind of editable text, but not really.  The cursor placement and input just sort of behaved buggy and strange as it couldn't deleted, but new input would write over it.  It was not a pleasant user experience :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering with my own conclusion that there is no answer.  There is no resolution here.  It's simply a limitation of the platform.